# Error: Could not find or load main class jar

Tags: java

I exported a Java project of mine from Eclipse to a JAR File, and after searching the internet for an hour, have still not resolved my problem. The jar file works on the computer that I compile, and exported it on, yet when I transfer it to my laptop it states that *"A Java Exception has occurred"* when I try to double click it, and when I run the code below, it retorts *"Error: Could not find or load main class jar"*

```
java -jar C:\Users\Me\Desktop\test.jar
```

I exported it once more after specifying to the MANIFEST.MF the location of my main class, yet the same error is being reported. I have seen the MANY other threads on this on this forum, yet the advice has either been too vague or just plain didn't work.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A note to anyone else getting this error, I was using a batch file to run my jar, and I accidentally wrote "java jar PATH" (I forgot the `-` before `jar`), and I got this error.

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of java you are running in your laptop, the error could present itself if you compiled your program with a different version that the one you are using to run it.

Comment: That was it! Oh my, I'm an idiot... Haha... I got my Laptop yesterday, and naturally installed the first link that I saw on google for Java Runtime Environment (SE 7), yet that was out of date relative to my other computer (which runs SE 8u25) Thanks!